# MCSE: Data Management and Analytics requirements overlap with MCSA: SQL Server 2016 Database Development

Tags: learning

I've been reviewing the requirements to get the [MCSE: Data Management and Analytics](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcse-data-management-analytics.aspx) certification, and was thinking of going the path of the [MCSA: SQL 2016 Database Development](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcsa-sql2016-database-development-certification.aspx) pre-req. The thing is there's an overlap in the requirements. The MCSA requires passing exam 70-761 and 70-762. To get the MCSE I need to take 1 exam from a list of about 12, 70-762 being one of the options. I'm confused about the requirement overlap of exam 70-762. Once I have the MCSA do I meet the stated requirements for the MCSE. Or do I need to take a 3rd exam from the list to qualify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are many ways to obtain the MCSA the 762 is included as a choice for those who have not previously taken it. If you have already taken it then you would need to choose a different exam to obtain your MCSE.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I was thinking that was probably the case.